# Using NOT on REST date query

Tags: 2013, rest, date-time, odata

I am able to filter for items created on a specific date with the following query (using today [03-06-2015] as an example):

```
"$filter=Created ge datetime'2015-03-06T05:00:00.000Z' and Created lt datetime'2015-03-07T05:00:00.000Z'"
```

But how do I check for dates that are NOT equal to today? I tried putting "not " before the first "Created" and wrapping the whole thing in parenthesis. I also tried putting "not" before the "ge" and "lt" operators.

Is this not possible to do without changing the query to the following?

```
"$filter=Created lt datetime'2015-03-06T05:00:00.000Z' or Created ge datetime'2015-03-07T05:00:00.000Z'"
```

Edit: I'm also noticing that `not substringof(x,y)` and `substringof(x,y) eq false` are also not working. For such a big push to REST calls, I'm not sure why there's so much that seems to have been forgotten or made very difficult to find.

Comment: Is this SP Online/O365 or is this on-prem? Filtering in REST does not behave exactly the same way on the two.

Comment: This is on-prem

Answer (score 2):

Since the original query:

```
$filter=Created ge datetime'<startdate>' and Created lt datetime'<enddate>'
```

**includes** all the items that have been created between `startdate` and `enddate`

the following query in opposite **excludes** items that have been created in this date interval:

```
$filter=Created lt datetime'<startdate>' or Created ge datetime'<enddate>'
```

**Example**

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Created lt datetime'2015-03-06T05:00:00.000Z' or Created ge datetime'2015-03-07T05:00:00.000Z'
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming, but I think this is the same example I used in my question. I was really just looking to know if there is a direct negation I could use for datetimes and substrings or if this was not possible.

Comment: Nope, it is not the same, the example the answer demonstrates how to return items that have been created NOT in the specified date interval

Comment: Sorry.. it seems you are very much correct. I accidentally put an "and" in my example instead of an "or" though I had successfully been using it this way in my application. The example I listed would not return anything at all.